# Applying two transforms to a message on the send port

Tags: mapping, biztalk, orchestration

I have an urgent need to send a canonical message (M1) out of an orchestration and need to map the canonical message to another message (M2). The resulting message (M2) has to be Wrapped in another request message (M3) before sending it to a web service.

I can't perform the initial transform in the orchestration as I can only deal with the canonical schema internally.

Whats the best way to achieve this 2 stage transform outside of the orchestration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a pipeline component that applies each map sequentially. Then configure the port to use a pipeline with this component.

```
private Stream ApplyMap(Stream originalStream, Type mapType)
{   
   var transform = TransformMetaData.For(mapType).Transform;
   var argList = TransformMetaData.For(mapType).ArgumentList;

   XmlReader input = XmlReader.Create(originalStream);
   Stream outputStream = new VirtualStream();

   using (var outputWriter = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream))
   {
      transform.Transform(new XPathDocument(input), argList, outputWriter, null);
   }
   outputStream.Flush();
   outputStream.Position = 0;

   XmlReader outputReader = XmlReader.Create(outputStream);
   return outputReader;
}
```

Then in the pipeline component's Execute method:

```
Type mapType1 = Type.GetType("YourMapNamespace.Map1, YourAssemblyName,...");
Type mapType2 = Type.GetType("YourMapNamespace.Map2, YourAssemblyName,...");

Stream originalStream = inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
Stream mappedStream = 
   ApplyMap(
     ApplyMap(originalStream, mapType1),
     mapType2
   );
inmsg.BodyPart.Data = mappedStream;
context.ResourceTracker.AddResource(mappedStream);
```

Note that this example does everything in memory so it could be a problem for large messages. I'll try to find a better example that uses streaming (or worse case, you can use VirtualStream to avoid keeping everything in memory)

Comment: Hi ckarras, I'll give this a shot. I suspect that the message size could grow considerably but I'll investigate what the possible limits are. A streaming example would be great whenever you can provide it! Many thanks! –

Comment: Microsoft already provides a pipeline component as a part of the ESB Toolkit's samples that allows you to execute a map inside your pipeline. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699836.aspx

Comment: @schellack I tried the ESB Guidance pipeline (in the first version) and it was loading the entire result in memory (even though it uses streaming internally). So I had to develop an alternative when I encountered larger messages. I'm not sure if this has been resolved in ESB Toolkit v2.

Comment: For a full pipeline component example that's similar to my answer, I found this: http://geekswithblogs.net/paulp/archive/2010/10/13/142270.aspx. As my answer, this one could still be improved by getting rid of the VirtualStream and doing the transformation progressively, as the stream is consumed. (I'll probably write a full example myself and publish it as a blog post once it's complete)

Comment: After more research, it seems the improvement I had in mind won't be possible by using BizTalk's transformation classes. The VirtualStream is still a good solution for large messages, the only problem is that the pipeline will do the whole transformation in a single burst, instead of distributing it evenly as the output stream is being consumed by BizTalk. So it's a good solution to minimize memory usage, but could theoretically impact concurrency if the CPU is overloaded.

Comment: What you're after is indeed possible, in a pure streaming fashion. Please, check the posts from for a class that you can use in your custom pipeline component. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/04/08/how-to-boost-message-transformations-using-the-xslcompiledtransform-class-extended.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the ESB Toolkit, the ideal approach would be to use an itinerary (Richard Seroter has a good article on that approach [here](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/esb-toolkit-executing-multiple-maps-in-sequence/)).  If that's not an option, here's an approach I've used in the past:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisromp/archive/2008/08/06/stacking-maps-in-biztalk-server.aspx

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. I already had a look at your solution and as you suggested , it would work as a temporary fix. I guess I was wondering if the was a "correct" way of achieving this - something closer to ckarras' suggestion. Thanks again!